# How do I run multiple version of the same Silverlight project side-by-side?

Tags: silverlight, visual-studio-2013, iis-express

I keep having a problem running multiple versions of the same solution. I am working on a new release of our Silverlight product, and it's located in a dev branch. Meanwhile I have to fix an issue in the deployed version, located in our maintenance branch.

Whenever I start up a VS (2013) instance of the maintenance version, my dev branch suddenly starts running the maintenance version instead. At least that's what I think is happening, because the UI looks like the maintenance version, and any breakpoint will say that the source file differs from the version built. The only way to get my dev version working again, is to close both VS instances, and open the dev version alone.

Does anyone have a clue what's going on? I have tried a lot of other things as well, but the only thing working is closing both VS instances:

1. Checked the build configuration
2. Checked that Silverlight debugging is enabled
3. Deleted bin/obj folders
4. Updated the Default.apsx file with so browser cache should be ruled out

UPDATE:

Ok, I found the reason, but not the fix. The project is configured to use IIS express and port 7751:

[image: Project settings]

When I check the applicationhost.config, I found the entry, and it looks something like this:

```
<site name="ProjectName" id="23">
    <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
        <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="xxxxxxxx\dev-branch\project" />
    </application>
    <bindings>
        <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:7751:localhost" />
    </bindings>
</site>
```

But I start up the maintenance version of the same solution, the virtual directory immediately changes path to the maintenance version instead (without running the project):

```
<site name="ProjectName" id="23">
    <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
        <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="xxxxxxxx\maintenance-branch\project" />
    </application>
    <bindings>
        <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:7751:localhost" />
    </bindings>
</site>
```

So now my question is - how do I ensure that it is possible to run multiple version of the same solution side-by-side?

Answer (score 0):

You should configure the project to run on different ports.

Comment: That's what I am doing at the moment, but when I merge I will loose the difference. I was hoping for a more permanent solution. I seem to recall a "use random port" in earlier versions of VS.